# Spring MVC Carousel

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, carousel

How to make images slider (carousel) in Java Spring MVC.

I have admin panel which upload the images to local drive.

I would like to display images from local drive to JSP page in carousel.

Please guide.

Also I tried one example from the link https://blog.e-zest.com/dynamic-carousel-built-using-javascript/  but I am getting javascript error.

Thanks,
Bhavin

Answer (score 0):

First you need to be able to serve your files to web browser. You can serve files from local drive using tomcat or web server (nginx, Apache httpd etc) built-in features without writing Java code or write a Spring controller to read files form drive and serve them if you need custom logic.

Then you could use one of javascript carousel plugins like [Slick](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) or another - there is a great choice of those.

Add needed scripts and css to your page and follow selected plugin instructions to create needed HTML with your JSP page.